# How to Edit InfoPath Form Web Part?

Tags: web-part, infopath, form, edit

I need to make changes to a SharePoint 2010 page that someone else created. I have full admin rights to the site. I was told that the page is nothing more than an InfoPath form embedded in to the page. When I click on edit on the Ribbon and go into edit mode, all I see are two web parts, **InfoPath Form Web Part [ 1]** and **InfoPath Form Web Part [2]**. VERY IMPORTANT: ***I cannot see any sign that this page or the web parts are associated with a list***. I tried playing around with the web part properties, and the ribbon features, but I cannot find any way to make actual edits. For example to open the form in InfoPath and make edits.

Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to edit the page?

UPDATE:

Here is an image showing what options are available in the ribbon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [multiple ways](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Edit-list-forms-using-InfoPath-2010-in-SharePoint-Designer-f86cf514-9a11-4613-a479-12a1a0132d22?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ) to edit the "InfoPath Form" associated with your site. Generally, the InfoPath Form will be associated to an existing list or library on your site. There are two main methods, to updating the form. Firstly, InfoPath using Browser. Secondly, SharePoint Designer.

**InfoPath**

1. To customize your list form in the browser, just browse to your form and then on the **List** tab, in the **Customize List** group, choose **Customize Form**.
2. Use InfoPath 2010 to create a new list form or customize and existing form

**SharePoint Designer**

1. Open site, using SharePoint Designer.
2. In **Navigation** Pane, select **Lists and Libraries**.
3. Open list you want to customize.
4. On the **List Settings** tab, in the **Actions** group, click **Design Forms** in InfoPath, and then choose the content type that you want to use for the list forms.

Comment: This is my problem and the point I was trying to stress in my question. The forms are not associated with any list. As a result, there is no List tab, or List and Libraries options to select in the ribbon. These options are just not there. I know how to open regularly set up Forms in InfoPath or Designer. That is easy. But what do I do in this case, where the InfoPath Form Web Part is embedded in to the page without the conventional options to edit???

Comment: Open the tool pane in the Web Part to open the InfoPath Form Web Part tool pane, in the List or Library list in the tool pane - is a document library or list displayed?

Comment: That's the problem, nothing is available like what you are explaining. There are no list or document library options available. It's as if this InfoPath form is not associated with any list at all. I've added an image to the original question to show you what options are available.

Comment: Yes, select "Web Part Properties" on the ribbon, and see if those details are displayed in the web part properties.

Comment: If not, can you post the image for what the properties currently indicate?